# Permission Error while using cloud CLI on new GCP Project

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have created a new GCP Project and linked to a billing account (Default project is already there)

But when I try to use the new Project with gcloud CLI, It's giving the following error. The same command is working fine If I use the same command on the default project.

```
~$ gcloud services list --enabled
ERROR: (gcloud.services.list) PERMISSION_DENIED: Not allowed to get project settings for project <Project Name>
```

What are the additional configurations required on the new Project?

Answer (score 1):

Please verify project id. Link is [here GCP](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/troubleshoot-config-deployment#not-allowed-to-get-project-settings)

Answer (score 0):

Run a check if the config you're using is pointing to the desired project.

```
gcloud config list project
```

Also, if you're using a Cloud SDK, you can also use `gcloud init` to verify if you've configured the correct authorization for the project.